# Google Apps Reply-to-List

Tags: google-workspace, mailing-list

I am a group administrator of an organization's Google Apps account.
My problem is when somebody send a mail to the mailing list, the person who want to respond by default will send the response to the sender, not to the list. (Of course if he or she push the Reply-To-All button it works, but many times they forget to use it.)
In an other organization we use a Sympa mailing server, which provide many configuration opportunity including Reply-To-List as a default behavior.
Do you know if it's possible in Google Apps?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google Groups for Business should be turned on for the domain, then, (adaptation from [Choose how Groups email replies are sent -Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/4600446?hl=en)):

### Change your Group’s reply setting

1. Open Google Groups for your domain.
2. Click My Groups > name of the group you want to edit.
3. Click Manage in the upper-right corner.
4. From the left-hand navigation menu, click Settings > Email Options > Post Replies.
5. Use the drop-down menu to select a choice, then click Save in the upper-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change an individual account to have "Reply All" as default in Gmail.

> If you'd like "Reply to all" to be your default option, click the gear
>   icon and choose **Settings**. Locate the **Default reply behavior** setting to
>   change the option. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page. You
>   can still choose to reply to just one person in each message, but
>   Reply to all will be the first option.

[image]

This is taken from the [Gmail help center](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6585?hl=en).

Comment: It won't solve my problem, because there are many list member and I can't tell all of them to apply this settings.
The Sympa can set in the email that the default Reply-to address for that particular email is the list itself, but in case of Google Apps I can't find this settings.